# How to post string to URL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a string like: `<0>book1<0>book2<0><0>book3<1>Version<1>`, and I have a URL: abc.com. I want to send a string to the URL from a Windows Phone.

I have searched in Google but I found nothing of any use, because the results were for web pages (.aspx), where as, I am using a C# class (.cs). I want create a method like this:

```
public void SendPost(string url, string postData)
{
...        
}
```

Comment: use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebClient`

```
public void SendPost(string url, string postData)
  {
      WebClient client = new WebClient();
      client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
      client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), postData);

  }

void client_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // error in uploading
    }
}
```

Comment: It get error : "An exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code" in  client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;

Comment: Error shows that your url is not in correct format.